# Accessing form element when name is an array and there are two radio buttons with the same name

Tags: javascript, webforms

I have a function that used to work before I changed the names of my form into arrays.  When you check yes or no for one radio button autoselect() chooses yes or no for another set of radio buttons.  The problem I'm having is that javascript will not let me access the element by name because there are two elements with the same name.  Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function autoselect(selectedOption, updateCompleted)
{
if(selectedOption.value=="No")
    updateCompleted[0].checked=true;
else
    updateCompleted[1].checked=true;
}
</script>

<input type="radio" onclick="autoselect(this,document.form<?php echo $i; ?>.elements['data[<?= $i; ?>][completed]']);" name="data[<?= $i ?>][needed]" value="Yes">Yes

<input type="radio" onclick="autoselect(this,document.form<?php echo $i; ?>.elements['data[<?= $i; ?>][completed]']);" name="data[<?= $i ?>][needed]" value="No">No

...

<input type="radio" id="completed<?php echo $i."1"; ?>" name="data[<?= $i ?>][completed]" value="Yes"><span id="completed<?php echo $i."3"; ?>">Yes</span>

<input type="radio" id="completed<?php echo $i."2"; ?>" name="data[<?= $i ?>][completed]" value="No"><span id="completed<?php echo $i."4"; ?>">No</span>
```

There are multiple forms with the same elements on each page, and their names are incremented using the $i index.

Comment: i just noticed that your radios also have an id, why can you not access it with the id

Comment: I ended up using the id for most of the form elements.  It turns out that this code does work, there was just another javascript function that was failing in the same onclick property preventing it from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to return an array of the items and then access the one you want with the index

```
var el1=$('input[name="elementName"]')[0];
var el2=$('input[name="elementName"]')[1];
```

etc

Comment: jquery probably would be the best way to handle this.  I'm trying to update a legacy application, without rewriting too much code.  I've resorted to using a hidden field with the id of the current form and appending that to the names of the radio button field's ids.